# scala list type mismatch

Tags: list, scala, type-inference

So I had list of tuples like this:

```
val rooms = List(("Hi", "mom"),("hi", "dad"))
val foo = rooms.map(arg =>{
                  var fields = List
                    ( new JField("greeting",arg._1),
                      new JField("recipient",arg._2))
                      new JObject(fields)})
```

And there was much happiness in the land, but when I changed list of room like so:

```
case class Room(greeting:String, recipient:String)
val rooms = List(Room("Hi", "mom"),Room("hi", "dad"))
val foo = rooms.map(arg =>{
                  var fields = List
                    ( new JField("greeting",arg.greeting),
                      new JField("recipient",arg.recipient))
                      new JObject(fields)})
```

I get:

```
[error] <file>: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.collection.immutable.List.type (with underlying type object List)
[error]  required: List[blueeyes.json.JsonAST.JValue]
[error]                       new JArray(fields)
```

So it appears that the list is now of Object instead of JField as it was before, why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you don't detach the `List` from its `(`:

```
var fields = List(
  new JField("greeting", arg.greeting),
  new JField("recipient", arg.recipient))
```

Basically, it's parsing like this:

```
var fields = List                         // assign the List companion object

(new JField("greeting", arg.greeting),    // construct a tuple with two items
  new JField("recipient", arg.recipient)) //   ...but don't use or assign it

new JObject(fields)                       // Make JObject containing the type
```

The error comes because the `JObject` constructor expects a `JValue` but you are passing it `fields` which has type `List.type`.

Comment: Also, the first version has the same problem (at least when I tried it). So there's not actually a difference between them.

Comment: Yes, I'm stupid. I was trying to simplify to make the question more clear.  The problem I had was I formated something like:  val a = List(    to something like  vale a = List <newline> (

Comment: `val fields = List` actually makes `fields` equal to the `List` object companion.